# Undo/change votes on old answers

Tags: feature-request, voting, old-answers

I've noticed a trend going on over the years. As newer answers come in (for example, the ever changing .NET Core libraries and specifications) I keep getting bogged down by answers that are no longer relevant, with better answers being lower down due to low scores because they are new.

I think it makes sense that votes should only be locked for 1-2 years, then allow people to undo a vote in order to re-cast it. This can allow people to undo a vote on an old answer in favor of a newer answer.

This can only be done perhaps if a *new* answer arrives to an old question (preventing people from trying to game the system, which I know is what vote locking was for). At the moment, people can only change the vote if the answer updates, but I propose it be allowed on new answers to an old question as well.

Old answers at the top are throwing people off completely, wasting lots of people's time later figuring out the top answer is actually out of date! If find this is starting to make Stack Overflow less and less reliable for me, with new valid and previously valid old answers mixed everywhere.

*(this would also have the effect of making people keep top answers up to date, or lose their top position for newer answers, which I think is good as newer generations of people join the site over years)*

Thoughts?

Comment: People can already undo a vote after a post has been edited.

Comment: That has nothing to do with my post. You must have skimmed through it.  Try re-reading again carefully.

Comment: Since you already said that people are unlikely to re-visit the same question (except maybe "how to undo last git change" :) ) why do you believe "unlocking" will provide measurable change in votes.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov LOL, I had a feeling someone might say that exact thing.  I didn't mean they would never, I meant it could take more time.  But, in time, people will be pushed to use newer frameworks and libraries, and eventually they will probably come looking for the newer answers.  As it stands, no one can undo an old vote and move more relevant ones up, which is worse. Some people will return, and of those, they can help the new answers rise up. That is still better than it is currently, even if they don't all return.

Comment: Votes shouldn't be locked at all.

Comment: Perhaps a new question should be asked about new libraries, instead of trying to shoehorn it into old questions about old versions of the library?

Comment: Reverting votes on answers which are not bad (just old) is just the wrong attempt at a solution, votes are not to be used like switches you can flip on and off at your leisure. Let me put it differently: it is not going to help float new answers to the top, people still need to upvote those which is not happening - that is the true problem here. Makes you wonder if it is a good idea to keep piling answers on old questions; probably not.

Comment: Well, creating the same question for a new situation would be pointless since it would be marked as duplicate. It's very common to have the same question require a different answer as time changes. That is what I am referring to.

Comment: If a different answer is required because the technology has changed, then it's a new question and should not be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: First of all, you are plain wrong.  Just because a tech changes doesn't mean a new question is needed.

Comment: I'm talking about changing how a feature of a software library might work, or related situations.  For example, someone might ask "How does many to many navs work in EF Core" (because it won't auto map without the fluent API) and you'll get an answer, but it's only workarounds until they implement it.  I can't tell you the number of times I looked for a question regarding ASP.NET MVC or something else, and the SAME question changes answers over time. I think any smart and experienced persons here know what I mean.

Comment: TypeScript is another - the same question will have different answers as it improves. JavaScript by itself keeps changing over time also.  It's NOT a new tech, just evolving.  The same answer may not hold true years later.

Comment: A prime example might be this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39879/why-doesnt-javascript-support-multithreading - The anser from 2008 is not correct, browsers do support it now (with limitations).  The Wikipedia page itself (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Web_worker&action=history&year=2009&month=12&tagfilter=) was created 2009 shortly after that answer, but those answers are very out of date. The new more valid answer is stuck buried down at the bottom. So, technology changed?  Yes.  Need new question?  NO.

Comment: Why would you undo votes on correct answers at the time? People can vote on multiple answers and if a new answer is more relevant now, it will be voted up as more users find it. The example of browsers is bad because not everyone uses the latest browsers. In fact I know some government departments that have to support IE8.

Comment: Wouldn't that also mean that old but correct answers loose their votes? Wouldn't that also mean that a worse answer posted later will show up on top eventually?

Comment: @tima The referenced question is asking about JavaScript supporting threading, and also asks about the future of it.  It is not being asked in the context you are suggesting. It's a great example in context of the question of threads in JS.

Comment: @BDL Lose in favor of more correct ones? Sure, why not?  Are you saying that worse answers cannot be voted on top today?  I seem to recall some of these in the past. Are you claiming that people will vote up bad answers, as if it doesn't happen already?

Answer (score 3):

Voting happens at that instant in time; if the answer was correct at that instant in time, there's no reason for us to detract from its correctness in spite of what's changed over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Like typos it happens, that you accidentally downvote or upvote a question or answer, but intended the opposite. Would be nice, if you could at least undo a wrong vote.